# A toggle button which once clicked initiates full screen window and if clicked again goes back to the normal state

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

My code in pyqt is simple:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.add_entry)

def add_entry(self):

            if QtCore.Qt.WindowFullScreen:
               MainWindow.showNormal()
            else :
                   MainWindow.showMaximized()
```

The toggle button when clicked however does its job it's showing full screen but on clicking again it's not reverting back to normal screen mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing things together. QtCore.Qt.WindowFullScreen is constant value - therefore your condition is always true. And at second - .showMaximized window method switch window object to the Qt.WindowMaximized state.

Here is how you should change it:

```
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        cb = QtGui.QPushButton('Switch', self)
        cb.move(20, 20)
        cb.clicked.connect(self.add_entry)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.show()

    def add_entry(self):
        if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowFullScreen:
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            self.showFullScreen()
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help sir,it really helped me out and i really appreciate it...